# Filtrar sólo por una parte del contenido de una columna en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Dada una tabla llamada `miTabla` y una columna llamada `code` del tipo `int (10)` con zerofill activado...

Quisiera saber cual sería la mejor manera de filtrar por una parte de la columna `code` en MySQL.

Supongamos que en dicha columna tengo valores como:

```
0700010101
0700010201
0700010301
0700010401
0700010501
0700010601
0700010701
0700020101
0700020201
0700020301
0700020401
0700020501
0700020601
0700020701
0800010101
0800010201
...
```

y quiero hacer un `SELECT` filtrando en `code` por:

- primeros dos números de `code` desde la izquierda... ejemplo `07`
- primeros dos números de `code` desde la izquierda y números en las posiciones 5 y 6 desde la izquierda. Ejemplo `08` y `01` .

¿Cuál sería la forma más eficaz de hacerlo en MySQL?

Comment: la verdad es que no deberías tener una columna que consiste en la composición de diferentes cosas (esto es la primera forma normal). ¿No tienes posibilidad de tener esto en columnas separadas?

Comment: @Lamak En realidad se trata de un sistema algo complejo. He ideado una especie de código compuesto en el cual cada dos números representan los valores siguientes : `ciclo, tiempo, semana, dia, hora`. En el sistema hay varias tablas con varias columnas parecidas a `code` que apuntan a datos en otras tablas mediante `JOIN` en las claves primarias-foráneas. Es como un código único y múltiple al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Es que justamente un  código compuesto es algo que no debería hacerse

Comment: @Lamak No creas. Por ejemplo el documento de identidad en muchos casos es un código compuesto que trae implícito un código de ciudad de nacimiento y otros datos. Lo mismo puede ocurrir con el código postal y otros... Si yo divido mi columna código en 5 columnas en una tabla que podría tener 15 columnas del tipo código tendría entonces 15x5 columnas. Y ninguna me serviría como clave foránea en las otras tablas. Como dije en otro comentario he optado por un tipo de columna que sirva para identificar 5 elementos distintos y sirva al mismo tiempo de FK en cualquier tabla.

Comment: Eso es porque tienes 15x5 datos diferentes, deberían estar en columnas diferentes. Entiendo que hay códigos compuestos, digo que en base de datos relacionales no deberían ir en una sola columna. Por algo es la **primera forma normal**

Comment: @Lamak no son 5 datos diferentes en cada columna sino una sola columna desde la cual, por la naturaleza de la aplicación que estoy desarrollando , necesito identificar en cada columna los 5 valores mencionados. Si los separo, para hacer una simple identificación tendría que llamar cada vez 5 columnas por cada valor, mantener un tal diseño sería complicado y hacer los JOINS sería tarea casi imposible.

Comment: La verdad no pretendo que cambies tu diseño. Pero no entiendo cómo pensar que hacer joins y filtros con un código compuesto puede ser más fácil. Ya ves los problemas que estás teniendo al tratar de hacer un simple filtro. Lo que normalmente se hace es que este código se separa en columnas distintas, pero asignando una columna llave, y es esta columna la que deberías llevar a las otras tablas para tus joins

Comment: @Lamak Entiendo. En realidad lo de los filtros es más para cuestiones de depuración-revisión. Por ejemplo, si quiero saber qué elementos he introducido del tiempo `07` y de la semana `01`. La app en producción hace `JOINS` usando como llaves cada valor de 10 dígitos con una tercera tabla auxiliar ya que son relaciones varios a varios. Mi columna de 10 dígitos es como una columna del tipo id, sólo que por requerimientos de la app necesito saber en cualquier momento a qué tiempo, ciclo, semana, día u hora pertenece **cualquier** elemento. Es en efecto como una columna id pero en forma de código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu solución pasa por usar LIKE

```
SELECT code FROM table WHERE code LIKE '07%';

SELECT code FROM table WHERE code LIKE '08__01%';
```

Tambien puedes usar REGEXP, aqui tienes información de [ambas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Podrías explicar brevemente cómo funciona `__` combinando con `LIKE`?

Comment: Un _ en un LIKE significa cualquier caracter.